# Django objection creation failing due to FOREIGN KEY constraint failure (IntegrityError )

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

My website has a comment section where user can leave comments on a product . The comments on the product page will be stored in a model called 'ProductReview'. Here is the code for the model :

```
    class ProductReview(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=20)
        stars = models.IntegerField()
        content = models.TextField(blank=True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now the view associated with the model are as follows **Note:The entire view isnt relevant to the error. The part relevant to the saving comment is the second 'request.POST' which I have denoted with a python
comment using #** :

```
def product(request, category_slug, product_slug):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, category__slug=category_slug, slug=product_slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddToCartForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            cart.add(product_id=product.id, quantity=quantity, update_quantity=False)
            messages.success(request, 'The product was added to the cart')
            return redirect('product', category_slug=category_slug, product_slug=product_slug)

    similar_products = list(product.category.products.exclude(id=product.id))

    # this part is for saving of the user comments to productreview model
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stars = request.POST.get('stars', 3)
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        created_by = request.user

        review = ProductReview.objects.create(product=product, name=name, stars=stars, content=content, created_by=created_by)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    # this marks the end of the code relevant to saving the user comment 

    if len(similar_products) >= 4:
        similar_products = random.sample(similar_products, 4)

    user_type = 0
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_type = UserType.objects.filter(created_by=request.user.id).values_list('user_type', flat=True)
        user_type = int(user_type[0])
    return render(request, 'product.html', {'product': product, 'similar_products': similar_products, 'user_type': user_type})
```

And finally the relevant part of the template 'product.html' which is referenced in the view

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user_type == 2 %}
            <div class="notification space-below">
                <form method="post" action=".">
                    {% csrf_token %}


                     <div class="field">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="text" name="name" value="{{ request.user }}" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Stars</label>
                        <div class="control">
                             <div class="select">
                                 <select name="stars">
                                     <option value="1">1</option>
                                     <option value="2">2</option>
                                     <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                                     <option value="4">4</option>
                                     <option value="5">5</option>

                                 </select>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Content</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea class="textarea" name="content"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <button class="button is-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            {% else %}
                <div>sign in with a buyer account to leave review</div>

            {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

Now when I try to fill the form in the product.html page and try to submit it ,I get the following error:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
IntegrityError at /smartwatch/apple-watch/
```

Can anyone tell what exactly is the issue with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this all comes to your model, especially to this single line:

```
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You are using `OneToOneField`. This means a single user will be able to leave a single review in your entire application. You are getting integrity errors probably because this user you've selected already has a review on a different product.

If this isn't what you want, use normal `ForeignKey` instead.

I think your intention was to ensure that a single user can leave only one review per product. In that case, you should try setting [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) between the `product` and `created_by` fields

Comment: Hey , thanks for the reply . But when I changed it to Foreign Key instead of One to One , the error is still occurring

Comment: Did you apply the changes to your database using migrations?

Comment: You are correct . I forgot to apply the migrations . It has been a long night! My brain is not working at full capacity . The error has now gone away and it works perfectly . Thanks a lot !